# How to convert Microsecond Value to CPU cycle calculation?

Tags: sql-server-2012, computer-science, cpu-usage, cpu-architecture, cpu-speed

How to convert Microsecond value into CPU cycle calculation, anybody know how to convert this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In multicore processors and modern architectures, it's not easy to come with a definition of 'spent' CPU cycles associated to a time interval consumed/elapsed in your program (I wonder SQL procedure/query according to your tags), like in the old pre-superscalar architectures.

I recommend you to find other metrics, procedures or special tools for measuring your performance.  I'm not an user of SQL Server, but all professional grade DBMS systems offer profiling tools for tuning DB/application performance.

Read this post and the user comments, it's related to the function QueryPerformanceCounter of Windows for approaching some kind of 'cycles' accounting. The discussion lights up why your cycle-based approach is not correct, from my point of view.

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20080908-00/?p=20963/

Comment: this is something i am looking like, if i have x procedure with its count = abc and its avgcpu = y then my TotalAvgCPU= abc*y which is in microseconds, then how we should convert this TotalAvgCPU value into CPU terms like MHz, GHz etc ?

Comment: MHz/GHz are not real measures of CPU performance under Wintel since ages of the Pentium processor which introduced superscalar features (parallel hardware execution of instructions).  What do you want to measure? In which context? Maybe you need a more precise measurement using things like "instrumentation" or profiling products. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_performance_analysis_tools

Comment: For SQL Server in particular, use SQLProfile tool. As I see, it can measure duration, CPU load %, threading issues, etc. https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/224587